# is there a template-method to access OpenCV element?

Tags: opencv, mat

I have some routines working with OpenCV Mat. This is one of them:

```
void drawCircles(Mat& image, const Mat points, Scalar color)
{
    // fix format of Matrix <-> hard coding

    //MatInfo(points);
    //getchar();

    CV_Assert(points.channels() == 2);
    //CV_Assert(points.depth() == CV_32FC2); // this is so restricted!!

    //CV_Assert(points.channels() == 2);
    //CV_Assert(points.depth() == CV_16UC2); 

    // added working for both row/col point vector

    Point2d p0;

    for (int i = 0; i < points.cols; i++)
    {   
        //p0.x = cvRound(points.at<Vec2i>(0,i)[0]);
        //p0.y = cvRound(points.at<Vec2i>(0,i)[1]);

        p0.x = cvRound(points.at<Vec2f>(0,i)[0]);
        p0.y = cvRound(points.at<Vec2f>(0,i)[1]);

        //p0.x = cvRound(points.at<Vec2d>(0,i)[0]);
        //p0.y = cvRound(points.at<Vec2d>(0,i)[1]);

        circle(image, p0, 5, color, 2, 8);
    }
}
```

which is used to draw circles on an image at given points.

I'm going fine with accessing Mat's element by matrixA.at(i,j). However, this is so specific. When the matrix's element type differs, the function cannot work. 
Is it possible to write sort-of template function in this case?? which is independent of Mat's element type??

Thank you

Edit01:

if it's something like

```
template <class T> 
void drawCircles(Mat_<T> img, const Mat points, Scalar cl)
{
  ..
  img.at<T>() = something;
  ..
}
```

then it would be perfect. But I've done searching with OpenCV docs and don't think this is supported with OpenCV MAT. Or am I missing some points?

Edit02: 
This is my try:

```
template <class Type>
void drawCircles(Mat& image, const Mat_<Vec<Type, 2> > points, Scalar color)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < points.cols; i++)
    {
        p0.x = cvRound(points.at<Vec<Type, 2>>(0,i)[0]);
        p0.y = cvRound(points.at<Vec<Type, 2>>(0,i)[1]);

        circle(image, p0, 5, color, 2, 8);
    }
}
```

and I call it with:

```
drawCircles(frame, Points, Scalar(255, 255, 255));
```

where Points is:

```
Mat Points = Mat(1, 5, CV_32FC2, 0);
```

Still it does not work out :(

Comment: It sounds like you want a function like `Point2d roundedElement(mat,row,col)`, which checks what type of matrix it is, uses the appropriate `at<T>` method for that type, and then returns the rounded result.  Does that sound correct?

Comment: @Mr.Vaughn: I tried to make it clearer with edit01

Comment: You could do something like that, but you would need to check the data type for `points`, and then call drawCircles(img,Mat_<U>(points),c1), with U being the appropriate type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all: Your design seems a bit broken to me. If "Points" is nothing but a 1xn matrix containing 2D vectors, it would be more appropriate to use a vector instead, e.g. `std::vector<Point2f>`.

However, with minor changes to your attempt the templated version should actually work:

```
template <typename T>
void drawCircles(InputArray _image, InputArray _points, Scalar color)
{
    Mat images = _image.getMat(), points = _points.getMat();
    CV_Assert(points.channels() == 2);

    for (int i = 0; i < points.cols; i++) {
        Vec<T,2>& v = points.at<Vec<T,2>>(0,i);

        Point2i p;
        p.x = cvRound(v[0]);
        p.y = cvRound(v[1]);

        circle(image, p, 5, color, 2, 8);
    }
}

// Usage:
drawCircles<float>(frame, Points, Scalar(255, 255, 255));
```

Comment: @Mr.Niko: your code works. Still I want to resolve my questions. Can I use "const Mat_<Vec<Type, 2> > points" in the function header/declaration? Eclipse check this as an error. So Mat cannot be passed as a template type??

Comment: That should be working as well if you pass an object of that type and not a plain "Mat" object. Can you be more specific on the error you get?

Comment: Thank you! it works for me now. It was just my own silly bug :D. Now I can use both Mat_ or InputArray