# template argument cannot be deduced - OpenCV Mat

Tags: templates, opencv, mat

I am using some variables in Mat type of OpenCV and make a call to a template function. But the argument template cannot be deduced and therefore creates a compilation error

calling function:

```
Rot2Homo(rot, tmpMat, ssTo);
```

called function template:

```
template <class NumType>
void Rot2Homo(cv::Mat_<cv::Vec<NumType, 1>> rot, cv::Mat_<cv::Vec<NumType, 1>> trans, cv::Mat& Homo)
{   
    Homo = cv::Mat::zeros(4,4, cv::Vec<NumType, 1>);

    rot.copyTo(Homo(Range(0,3), Range(0,3)));
    trans.copyTo(Homo(Range(0,3), Range(3,4)));
    Homo.at<cv::Vec<NumType, 1>>(3,3) = 1; 

    return Homo;
}
```

the compiled error:

```
error C2784: 'void Rot2Homo(cv::Mat_<cv::Vec<NumType,1>>,cv::Mat_<cv::Vec<NumType,1>>,cv::Mat &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'cv::Mat_<cv::Vec<NumType,1>>' from 'cv::Mat'
```

this similar usage was indicated and solved successfully in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13898402/is-there-a-template-method-to-access-opencv-element). But here it comes the error.

Thanks for any hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify `NumType` when you call the function `Rot2Homo`, for example write `Rot2Homo<float>(...);` when you call it.

The template types must be determined at runtime. Templating is not some kind of runtime guess, it's a way to write for any type, then use it for any given type when you need it.

Comment: hix! shame on me! I forgot the call syntax